# Редактирование цвета части текста в Visio

Tags: c#, visio, office-interop

Есть приложение, редактирующее документ Visio через Interop. Не могу найти пример как можно изменить цвет части текста в фигуре. Через разбор самого файла (распаковка .vsdx) тоже не получилось понять, текст делится на куски с установкой индексов, а стиль для индексов хранится отдельно. Как это редактировать на c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо отредактировать цвет части текста у формы shape:

```
var ch = shape.Characters;
ch.Begin = 2;//символ с которого меняем цвет
ch.End = 4;//конечный символ
ch.set_CharProps((short)VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor, (short)VisDefaultColors.visDarkRed);//это для замены на стандартные цвета палитры
```

для замены на произвольный цвет можно делать так:

```
Visio.Cell colorCell = shape.get_CellsSRC((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter,(short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowCharacter,(short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor);
colorCell.FormulaForceU = "RGB(0, 255, 255)";
```

Comment: Есть один нюанс - при замене текста, например shape.Text = shape.Text.Replace(...); слетают выставленные настройки цвета.